# Two blank lines between figures

Tags: vskip

I am working on a project. The space between two figures if placed one below other is required to be 2 lines.

my documentclass line is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn,openright]{book}
```

So I assume I can use:

```
\vskip 24pt
```

is this allright? It does compile, but is this actually two lines skip? Or do I also need to count space between lines? how many pt is that?

Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn,openright]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label1}
\end{figure}
\vskip 24pt
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you provide code of a minimum working example, which others can compile? It's unclear weather you add figures directly or using floats. I guess you probably are looking for something like `\bigskip\bigskip` or `\vspace{2\baselineskip}` between figures.

Comment: When using floats (like `\begin{figure...`) the spacing before and after depends on the surrounding material. You can put two graphics within one `{figure}` and speciify the spacing between them. But as you have not bothered to show any code I can't be bothered to try and help any further. --- GOM

Comment: Do you always want the images to stay together with this 2-lines-separation arrangement? If yes, you would rather put them inside one `figure` environment, including `\vskip` if you like. Otherwise, the images might as well be placed on separate pages depending on surroundings.